# Swift programmatically dialing with international codes

Tags: swift

I have been building an app to programmatically dial a number created from a local service provider, an access code, and then the contact you would like to dial.  I have successfully managed to get the phone to dial out using the following code:

```
@IBAction func dialButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    fetchServiceDetails()

    if serviceNumber == "0" {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Service Provider", message: "Please create a service profile in the Settings page.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {

    let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(self.serviceNumber)"+",,"+(self.servicePin)+"#,,"+(numberDisplay.text.self)!)
    println(url)
    saveRecents()
    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    if (application.canOpenURL(url!)) {
        application.openURL(url!)

    }


}
}
```

This works correctly for calling regular numbers.  However I cannot get it to dial anything with an international dialing code.

The app goes to the iPhone calling page with the full number generated, however when it gets to the last number (specifically) the character '+' the phone does not dial any further numbers.  The call is still active, it just does not finish dialing.  As far as I am aware apple does dial this character.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,  I have found the solution,  apologies for this. But for anyone interested in doing the same thing the solution is as follows.

The problem is not with swift or iOS.  Although I am not sure why it will not dial the '+' symbol there is a way around this.  This is by replacing all occurrences of '+' with '00'. This can be used instead of the + for international dialling code.  So instead of +44 for the United Kingdom,  it will dial 0044.

Comment: does it happens by default? Or we have to replace 00 for + ?